# Is currentTime supposed to start on audioContext creation or on creation of node graph objects?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

In the w3c specification this sentence exists:

> **currentTime**
>
> This is
>   a time in seconds which starts at zero when the context is created and increases in real-time

Now when I create piece of code with just the audioContext initialized and run a setInterval to output audioContext.currentTime I get back nothing but 0's.

```
var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();

setInterval(getTime,1000);

    function getTime() {

        console.log(audioContext.currentTime);   // 0
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly6tQ/

*However*

If I add a node graph object the currentTime begins outputting.

```
   var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();

    var osc = audioContext.createOscillator();


setInterval(getTime,1000);

    function getTime() {

        console.log(audioContext.currentTime);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly6tQ/1/

So I figure that either....

1. The initialization of the audioContext really means the first instance of creating something in the node graph.
2. Chrome ( which is the browser I'm using )  implemented it different than the spec
3. I'm missing something

Thank you.

Comment: On firefox it works like the spec, so that would mean it has something to do with Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem with Chrome, hopefully it'll get fixed soon.